# rational application developer - WAS server synchronize

Tags: websphere, rad, websphere-8

I'm a newbie in RAD ide and currently I always restarts the server everytime I make a change.
I'm wondering what is usually the most efficient way when deploying an ear file to WAS upon code changes.

1) If the WAS is auto synchronize,  does it mean that on every ctrl+s I make, it will redeploy immediately?

2) If auto synchronize is off, does changing a resources like jsp or xhtml pages would reflect without restart? How about changing java codes?

As much as I would like to try these right now, I do not have a license of RAD at home.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should try to avoid restarting server as much as possible, as it takes time. It is better to Republish, or remove and then add application to server.

*1) If the WAS is auto synchronize, does it mean that on every ctrl+s I make, it will redeploy immediately?*

Not immediately, it depends on the `Publishing interval` setting in the Server settings > Publishing (I don't remember the default, it is about 10-15 sec).

*2) If auto synchronize is off, does changing a resources like jsp or xhtml pages would reflect without restart? How about changing java codes?*

Restart has nothing to do with that, only republishing.

Behavior depends on other publishing options - In the `Publishing settings for WAS` in server settings you have the following options:

- Run server with resources within the workspace
- Run server with resources on Server

If you run from workspace, changes will be detected and application will reflect changes (if change in the java code application will be restarted).
If you run with on Server setting, then changes will not be reflected until republish not restart.

Restart is only required, if you change some settings on the server, e.g. changing datasource settings, security settings, etc..

For synchronizing - if you have large project, and making lots of changes it is usually better to temporary remove application from the server to avid constant republishing or disable automatic publishing.